# Is there any way to see Civilization V's civilopedia without activating the game?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there any way to browse the Civilopedia for Civilization V without entering the game, for example by browsing some online source or opening some file?

Comment: You beat me to this question.  I was looking at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/upgrade-paths-for-units-in-civilization-5) and I thought to myself "I'll just look through Civilopedia and help this guy out."   Except I don't own the game...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made this [online version of the civilopedia](http://civilopedia5.com/).

Comment: very cool, is it complete?  Is this your own site?

Comment: Yes it is my site. It is not complete, but I hope in the nearest future I will make all parts

Comment: Very nice work! Though unfortunately it is very outdated since all data seems to be correct only to the unpatched version and all DLC-only civs and units are missing.

Comment: The link is dead as of this comment's posting.

Answer (score 5):

I have never seen this for any version of Civilization, having played since Civilization 2. This is why I keep linking to the [Manual](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=380015) everywhere.

What's worse, in Civilization 4, you could view the Civilpedia from the main menu. However, this appears to be missing from Civilization 5?

Answer (score 5):

<s>As of September 2010, there is currently no way to see the Civilopedia without starting up the game, and in addition, having to actually *start* playing a game to access it. Though Civ IV had an option to access its Civilopedia from the menu, that feature is missing in Civ V.</s>

Something to keep an eye on would be [Wikia's](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Civilization_V) Civ V article, which seems to have a good start on their Leaders and Buildings articles, but is sparse in most other areas. The [CivFanatics](http://www.civfanatics.com/) website also had a complete Civilopedia on their site for Civ IV, so I imagine it will also be a good resource in the future.

As of the June 2011 update, the Civilopedia can now be accessed through the main menu under "Other."

Comment: "CivFanatics website also had a complete Civilopedia on their site for Civ V" do you mean Civ IV?

Comment: Oops, yep, edited to fix. Silly typos.

Comment: As of the June 2011 update, you can now access the Civilopedia from the main menu.