# What happens to ranged promotions when the unit becomes melee?

Tags: civilization-5

Some [upgrade paths](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/upgrade-paths-for-units-in-civilization-5) transform a unit from a ranged one to a melee one - for example, a crossbowman normally upgrades to a rifleman. However, ranged units get different damage-increasing promotions from melee units.

What happens to those ranged-damage promotions in that case? Do they still apply, or are they completely wasted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ranged combat specific promotions are wasted if the unit is upgraded to a melee unit.

Comment: Probably a pointless comment, but why is a crossbowman considered ranged when a rifleman isn't?