# Is there a chart showing all unit upgrade paths in Civilization 5 Gods & Kings?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Is there a chart showing the upgrade paths for the units? Something like

Warrior → Spearman → Pikeman...

for all of the units, similar to [the chart on this site for vanilla](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8102/122).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although not as pretty as the [chart on the other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8102/122), I made a basic version which is generated directly from the game files, and includes all unique units:

(*click on the image for a larger version*)

[image]

Notes:

- Each column represents one era.
- Dotted lines represent upgrades by ruins (though it's hard to see that the Scout -> Archer arrow is dotted).
- Grey lines represent special UU upgrade paths.
- The unit "combat type", listed under the unit name, controls which promotions are available to it.

  - Some unique units, however, have a different combat type than their "parent" unit - their combat type is then listed in square brackets after their name.
- Units that are not upgradeable from anything and that do not upgrade to anything are omitted from the graph from brevity. These are the carrier, marine, paratrooper, missile cruiser, all missiles and all non-combat units.

In addition, there's [a similar graph posted over at civfanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=468178). It's (much) prettier and lists strategic resources needed for each unit, though it does not list UUs.

Comment: May I ask what software you used to generate the graph once you pulled the data from XML?

Comment: @Adam I've used the `dot` layout engine of [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).