# Is there a chart showing all unit upgrade paths in Civilization 5 Brave New World?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Is there a chart showing the upgrade paths for the units? Something like

Warrior → Spearman → Pikeman...

for all of the units, similar to [the chart on this site for vanilla](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8102/122) and [for Gods and Kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/74301/122).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I made a basic version which is generated directly from the game files, and includes all unique units:

<sub>*(click on the image for a larger version)*</sub>
[image: BNW upgrade chart]

Notes:

- Each column represents one era.
- Dotted lines represent upgrades by ruins.
- Grey lines represent special UU upgrade paths.
- The unit "combat type", listed under the unit name, controls which promotions are available to it.
- Missiles and non-combat units cannot be upgraded and are omitted from the chart for brevity.

Comment: What did you use to generate this?

Comment: @DanRasmussen a Python script to extract the data from the game data files and [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for laying out the graph.

Comment: +1, graphviz. (Why didn't you export it as svg though?) Also if you have some control on the Graphviz output, you could try make the Scout-Archer edge more evident by changing the edge to (say) `scout:e -> archer:e`

Comment: @badp good idea, but ended up using the `minlen` attribute, worked well.

Comment: @Oak, you must be a good game programmer or the 'other one' (the good game hacker and crack maker) +1 though.=D

Comment: Thanks a lot for this effort and awesomely useful product, bro.

Answer (score 7):

I made my own chart for this:
[image: Unit upgrade picture]

[Link to the spreadsheet](http://lewthwaite.com.au/Civ5/Civ5BNW-Units.xlsx)